# Unable to solve using exact method after finding integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve the following problem, but I am getting stuck...

we have: $-y^2dx + x^2dy = 0$

given: $u(x,y) = \frac{1}{(x-y)^2}$

both have partial derivative: $\frac{-2xy}{(x-y)^3}$

so we have the exact equation: $\frac{-y^2}{(x-y)^2}dx + \frac{x^2}{(x-y)^2}dy = 0$

now, I try integrate the dx expression: $\int\frac{-y^2}{(x-y)^2}dx$

This gives me: $\frac{y^2}{(x-y)} + g(y)$

Differentiating with respect to y gives: $\frac{-y(y-2x)}{(y-x)^2} +g'(y)$

I have checked my work for the above integral and derivative and also used an online calculator to verify that they are correct. Every other problem of this type that I have tried has had something meaningful come of:

$\frac{-y(y-2x)}{(y-x)^2} +g'(y) = \frac{x^2}{(x-y)^2}$

However, I have not been able to get anywhere using this to try to find a value for $g(y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that now you calculate $g$, so you solve for $g'(y)$, getting $\frac{x^2+y(y-2x)}{(x-y)^2}=1$ so $g(y)$ can be chosen to be $y$, so the implicit solution is $\frac{y^2}{x-y}+y=C$, assuming your prior steps were correct.

Comment: Ahh I see. I had assumed I had made a mistake in how I was approaching the problem, but really I just needed to follow through. Thank you!

Comment: @dminzi My guess is that you got confused because it looked superficially like $g'(y)$ depended explicitly on $x$, which obviously cannot be the case. But if it looks like that might be the case, do the algebra anyway; if you find that it really does depend on $x$, then you've confirmed that you definitely made an error earlier.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly right. I shuffled things around a little bit, but as soon I thought that g'(y) was dependant on x I stopped.